# Layout Updates in Magento 2.3.4 has changed and needs further clarification

Tags: magento2

The link referred to in this exerpt of Magento 2.3.4 release note does not clearly state how to define the physical file.

You can no longer specify an entity-specific layout update with text but instead must create a physical file that contains the layout updates and select it for use. The name of the file containing an update must follow the conventions described here.